# MySQL - Inserting values from 3 different tables

Tags: mysql

I'm new to MySQL and databases in general. I'm currently trying to fill a table with default values as well as values from 3 other tables.

This is just a quick sketch up of what I have:

```
INSERT INTO person(firstName, height, weight) VALUES ('John', 10, 20);  
INSERT INTO address(street, city) VALUES ('8777 Road', 'Detroit');  
INSERT INTO building(name, addressID) SELECT 'Building1', ID FROM address;  
INSERT INTO map(personID, addressID, buildingID, name) SELECT ????
```

I'm not really sure what to do for the last line. I know I should be using something along the lines of `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, but I'm not really sure how as I'm getting syntax errors by trying to do so.

I currently have:

```
INSERT INTO map(personID, addressID, buildingID, name) SELECT person.ID, address.ID, building.ID, 'Name1' FROM person LEFT OUTER JOIN address LEFT OUTER JOIN building
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: JOIN on what? The columns to join on need to be specified. However, in your case you probably want to get the last inserted ID's from each query.

Comment: Without knowing the structure of your tables, it's not possible to see how to join them. In theory one would have to call LAST_INSERT_ID() after every INSERT, save it somewhere, be sure that no one else inserted something in the meanwhile, and then use all these IDs in the last query. In practice, that almost surely won't work.

Comment: Alright, that makes more sense. Thank you for the answers. I'll play around with it a bit.

Comment: @Ashalynd of course it will work, because LAST_INSERT_ID() is session specific. It will work.

Comment: Ah interesting, didn't know that, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first two queries are fine but you run into trouble with the third.

```
INSERT INTO building(name, addressID) SELECT 'Building1', ID FROM address;
```

Will insert the name 'Building1' attached to every single addressID in the DB, so if you have 2 addresses, it will insert 2 rows, 3 addresses, 3 rows etc.
It's surely not what you want.
However, you can take advantage of `LAST_INSERT_ID()` which will allow you to get the newly created ID's for each table.

Here is probably what you want (I added `@name` since you didn't specify a name for the map) [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a332c/1)

```
SET @name = 'some map';

INSERT INTO person(firstName, height, weight) 
VALUES ('John', 10, 20);

SET @personID = LAST_INSERT_ID();

INSERT INTO address(street, city)
VALUES ('8777 Road', 'Detroit');

SET @addressID = LAST_INSERT_ID();

INSERT INTO building(name,addressID) 
VALUES ('Building1',@addressID);

SET @buildingID = LAST_INSERT_ID();

INSERT INTO map(personID, addressID, buildingID, name)
VALUES(@personID,@addressID,@buildingID,@name);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed for what I'm doing currently. Thank you!